# torch circular import AttributeError

Tags: pytorch, tensor, torch, ubuntu-22.04, layout-parser

I am trying to use a script that uses torch but I keep getting this Attribute Error:

`AttributeError: partially initialized module 'torch' has no attribute 'Tensor' (most likely due to a circular import)`

I have tried running

```
pip3 uninstall torch
pip3 uninstall torchvision
pip3 uninstall torchaudio
pip3 install torch
pip3 install torchvision
pip3 install torchaudio
```

But this has not worked for me. Does anybody know how I can fix this? Any help would be greatly greatly appreciated!

Comment: How are the imports in the file you are trying to execute?

Comment: import detectron2.utils.comm as com
import detectron2.data.transforms as T
from detectron2.checkpoint import DetectionCheckpointer
from detectron2.config import get_cfg
from detectron2.data import DatasetMapper, build_detection_train_loader

from detectron2.data.datasets import register_coco_instances

from detectron2.engine import (
    DefaultTrainer,
    default_argument_parser,
    default_setup,
    hooks,
    launch,
)
from detectron2.evaluation import (
    COCOEvaluator,
    verify_results,
)
from detectron2.modeling import GeneralizedRCNNWithTTA
import pandas as pd

Comment: @Ivan above are the imports I included in my file